# Intercept all function calls inside a intercepted function by aspectj

Tags: java, reflection, aspectj

I am new to AspectJ and reflections What I want to achieve is something like In the below example:

A test class :

```
    public class Sample {
    Home home = new Home();
    Account account = new Account();
    AccountAuthentication accountAuthentication = new AccountAuthentication();

    @Test
    public void loginInvalidCredentials(){
    home.clickOnAccount();
    account.login("Admin", "secret");
    accountAuthentication.waitForPage();
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

I want to log Output something like this :

```
packageName.Sample.loginInvalidCredentials 
    packageName.Home.clickOnAccount();
    packageName.Account.login(userName = "Admin", Password ="secret");
    packageName.AccountAuthentication.waitForPage();
    packageName.Assert.assertTrue(value= true);
```

I have accessed the name of function `packageName.Sample.loginInvalidCredentials` with AspectJ

```
@Aspect
public class AspectClass {
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.testng.annotations.Test)")
    public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
        Method method = MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod();
        String methodName = method.getName();
        System.out.println("Aspect called for method "+ point.getSignature().getDeclaringType().name +"."+methodName);

        try { 
             //TODO intercept each function call inside the method without any custom anotation and get the value of parameters as well
              joinPoint.proceed();
             } 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that the convention here is to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the question. Your code has dependent classes which stop me from compiling and running your code, unless I define those classes by myself, which would have been jour job. This is your free shot, I am doing it this time. :-)

Comment: Please also note that the technical term is "methods", not "functions" in Java. Java is not a functional language.

Comment: Hi, @kriegaex Thanks for the suggestions Sory for mistakes as this was my first time on Stack Overflow, I will take this into consideration next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that

- you use full AspectJ and not something like Spring AOP (because then the answer would not apply),
- you do **not** want to record method calls recursively but just the ones directly called from your `@Test` methods. For example, if `Account.login(..)` would internally call `Account.checkPassword(..)`, it should not be recorded. That would also be possible, but then the solution would look differently.
- all you want to do is log test execution and not do anything else, so an `@Around` advice is not necessary, `@Before` is enough.

**Dummy application classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Account {
  public void login(String user, String password) {
    checkPassword(password);
  }

  public void checkPassword(String password) {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class AccountAuthentication {
  public void waitForPage() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Home {
  public void clickOnAccount() {
    doSomethingElse();
  }

  public void doSomethingElse() {}
}
```

**Marker annotation:**

I created this one myself because I was too lazy to set up a project with TestNG which I normally do not use.

```java
package org.testng.annotations;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface Test {}
```

**Sample application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Sample {
  Home home = new Home();
  Account account = new Account();
  AccountAuthentication accountAuthentication = new AccountAuthentication();

  @Test
  public void loginInvalidCredentials() {
    home.clickOnAccount();
    account.login("Admin", "secret");
    accountAuthentication.waitForPage();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Sample().loginInvalidCredentials();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class TestExecutionLogger {
  @Before("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.testng.annotations.Test)")
  public void logTest(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
  }

  @Before("call(* *(..)) && withincode(@org.testng.annotations.Test * *(..))")
  public void logTestActions(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("  " + joinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Sample.loginInvalidCredentials())
  call(void de.scrum_master.app.Home.clickOnAccount())
  call(void de.scrum_master.app.Account.login(String, String))
  call(void de.scrum_master.app.AccountAuthentication.waitForPage())
```

---

Of course you can refine your aspect if you really think you need to strip the plain method names from the informative AspectJ log output:

```java
  @Before("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(org.testng.annotations.Test)")
  public void logTest(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint.getSignature());
  }

  @Before("call(* *(..)) && withincode(@org.testng.annotations.Test * *(..))")
  public void logTestActions(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("  " + joinPoint.getSignature());
  }
```

```
void de.scrum_master.app.Sample.loginInvalidCredentials()
  void de.scrum_master.app.Home.clickOnAccount()
  void de.scrum_master.app.Account.login(String, String)
  void de.scrum_master.app.AccountAuthentication.waitForPage()
```

You can further refine it if you deliberately want to remove the method's return type or include the actual parameter values like in your example, which is easily possible via `JoinPoint.getArgs()`, but I leave that up to you. Your question was about pointcuts, not about how to extract which information from joinpoints.